# Discrepency between FormGroup object and its valid property in reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm adding an asynchronous validator dynamically before saving the form , I'm getting a weird issue.

when I print the entire form group object in console , the valid property is true .
But if I print it separately , the valid property is false

[Screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnviD.png)

`

```
save() {
    this.form.addAsyncValidators([
      FormValidator.validate()
    ]);

    this.form.updateValueAndValidity();

    console.log(this.form) // valid property is true here when I print the entire object
    console.log(this.form.valid) // valid property is false here
  }
```

`

Comment: when you `console.log` an object it is not a snapshot, it might change by the time you open it

Comment: so, even if the object says valid property is true , is it now obsolete?

Comment: yep, if you want to get current state, use debugger, or make clone of an object that won't change

Comment: With a async validator the "status" of the form can be `PENDING`. So check the status or check the form.valid some ms later.